# SVM training issue for a simple dataset (Opencv 2.4.9)

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

I'm trying a simple example to learn SVM in OpenCV, I'm not getting the right support vectors after training. Need some help in understanding the issue.
My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

Mat frame(Size(640,360), CV_8UC3, Scalar::all(255));
float train[15][2] = { {296, 296}, {296, 312}, {312,   8}, {312,  56}, {312,  88}, {328,  88}, {328, 104}, {328, 264}, {344,   8}, {344,  40}, {360,   8}, {360,  56}, {376,   8}, {376,  40}, {376,  56} };
Mat trainingDataMat(15, 2, CV_32FC1, train);
float labels[15] = { -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
Mat labelsMat(15, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

CvSVMParams param;
param.svm_type     = CvSVM::C_SVC;
param.C            = 0.1;
param.kernel_type  = SVM::LINEAR;
param.term_crit    = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 1e-6);

CvSVM SVM;

SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), param);
cout<< "Training Finished..." << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < frame.rows; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < frame.cols; ++j) {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << i,j);
        float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);
        //cout << response << endl;
        if(response == 1) {
            frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = 0;
        } else {
            frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = 0;
        }
    }
}
for(int dis = 0; dis < trainingDataMat.rows; dis++) {
    if(labels[dis] == 1) {
        circle(frame, Point((int)train[dis][0], (int)train[dis][1]), 3, Scalar (0, 0, 0), -1);
    } else {
        circle(frame, Point((int)train[dis][0], (int)train[dis][1]), 3, Scalar (0, 255, 0), -1);
    }
}    
int n = SVM.get_support_vector_count();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          const float* v = SVM.get_support_vector(i);
          cout << "support Vectors : " << v[0] << " " << v[1] <<endl;
          circle(frame,Point((int)v[0], (int)v[1]), 6, Scalar(128, 128, 128), 2, 8);
}
imwrite("frame.jpg",frame);
imshow("output", frame);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

[Output image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwdrK.jpg)

The SVM line is not separating the two classes as I expect.

Result for Support Vector is

```
 support Vectors : 0 0.0125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVM should be OK. I think the problem lies in your display. When you call your `circle(frame, Point((int)train[dis][0], (int)train[dis][1]), 3, Scalar (0, 0, 0), -1);`, OpenCV understands that you want a circle in row number `train[dis][1]` and column number `train[dis][0]`. This is not what you want because a specificity of OpenCV is that it uses different coordinate systems for matrices and points. `image.at<float>(Point(i,j))` is equivalent to `image.at<float>(j,i)`.

Try replacing your `circle` calls with this:

```
if(labels[dis] == 1) {
    circle(frame, Point((int)train[dis][1], (int)train[dis][0]), 3, Scalar (0, 0, 0), -1);
} else {
    circle(frame, Point((int)train[dis][1], (int)train[dis][0]), 3, Scalar (0, 255, 0), -1);
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Sunreef, it helped, but still i'm getting the support vectors as, `support Vectors : 0.0125 0`

Comment: It doesn't seem so absurd to me since the separation between your two groups is vertical (hence the normal vector should be x =/= 0 and y = 0).
@venkatsubramanian

Comment: I'm using **Opencv 2.4.9**, I tried the SVM example (non_linear_svms.cpp) from the src file, and I'm getting the support vectors as `Support Vectors :-0.06105730 0.0133702`, is it correct? or the Opencv bug?, my output image is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzXZDZFGar7BdVBUekthYm1yVlk/view the support vector is drawn in the top left corner, and the output in the opencv docs is http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_images/result1.png, difference between my image and opencv's example image is the lack of support vector point markers